# "Even so", "nevertheless" interchangeable?

Tags: word-order, conjunctions

The below sentence is from my English quiz.  The choices are 1. even so, 2. nevertheless. The correct answer is "nevertheless". Why "even so" can not be used in this case? I search the internet and found many said that they are interchangeable.

> The weather forecast for the week was terrible, but we **nevertheless** decided to go ahead with our planned trip to the beach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the example sentence had been written with a slightly different word order:

> The weather forecast for the week was terrible, but **nevertheless** we decided to go ahead with our planned trip to the beach.

Then **even so** could be substituted for **nevertheless**.  Both have a meaning similar to "Despite that being the case":

> The weather forecast for the week was terrible, but **even so** we decided to go ahead with our planned trip to the beach.

But as it is written, **even so** cannot be substituted for **nevertheless**.

> The weather forecast for the week was terrible, but we **nevertheless** decided to go ahead with our planned trip to the beach.

The biggest problem is that "so decided" is a set phrase in some formal contexts.  For example, "Having so decided" has a meaning similar to "Because he said so".  "Even" does not work well as a modifier in this context:

> The weather forecast for the week was terrible, but we even **so decided** to go ahead with our planned trip to the beach.

Comment: Garner writes about **but nevertheless**: _To cure this redundancy, drop either word. **Nevertheless** is typically the one to drop.  If special emphasis is needed, either **but . . . still** or a construction with **though** or **although** is the better choice._ Perhaps the same goes for **but even so**.

Comment: @MvLog -- Your comment would make a good answer.